TrollStore IOS swift Get Installed Apps about LSApplicationWorkspace.default().allApplications()
https://github.com/Lessica/TrollFools
I was reading through this repository and found a code snippet about getting all installed apps on an ios device:
let allAppList: [LSApplicationProxy] = LSApplicationWorkspace.default().allApplications();

When I download and install tipa from the repository's distribution (TrollStore), I can get the list of all installed apps. But when I compile the install using xcode I can't get the list of apps.
I don't understand why this is happening？

If you were able to get a list of all apps installed on an iOS device, that would be a really huge security leak.
Not going to happen.

But it's happened, and that's TrollStore
